# Google compute engine stuck on connecting, when connect using SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

The Google compute engine stuck on connecting, when connect using SSH.
This is the screen that it's stuck on:
[image]

Comment: Did you tried ```gcloud compute ssh example-instance --zone=us-central1-a``` as per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh)

Comment: Please post more details about this instance. New, or running for a year? Connect via the serial port and review the boot/startup logs. Firewall settings? Results from running an `ssh -v`. Show some work on how what you have tried beyond a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Try either of the steps to resolve your issue:

1. There may be a chance for SSH key expiration . You can check that from VM instance details ---> SSH keys. If the ssh key is expired, create a new ssh key

   Create a new SSH key on google cloud shell and use the public key created by the concerned vm.

   ```
    - ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME] -C [USERNAME]
    - ssh -i [PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY] [USERNAME]@[EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS]
   ```
2. Try to enable OS Login by setting metadata values at the instance or project level. To set these values, you can use either the Google Cloud Console  or the gcloud command line tool. By enabling OSlogin you can connect to ssh without getting stuck on the connecting page.

You can refer the link to enable OS Login:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin